# Optimizing how my jQuery code is written

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimization

I have just currently started learning jQuery and I seem to be able to get it work how I want but I feel that the way that I am writting it is not very efficient. Could anyone assist me in this example below:

```
$('.tiles-wrapper').css({top:'50%',left:'50%',margin:'-'+($('.tiles-wrapper').height() / 2)+'px 0 0 -'+($('.tiles-wrapper').width() / 2)+'px'});

    $(window).resize(function() {
        $('.tiles-wrapper').css({top:'50%',left:'50%',margin:'-'+($('.tiles-wrapper').height() / 2)+'px 0 0 -'+($('.tiles-wrapper').width() / 2)+'px'});
    });
```

So here I am positioning a div in the center of the screen. And then it also does it again on window resize as its contents width properties are percentage values. It works perfectly but I can't help but feel that there must be a better way to write this. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Use a variable for `$('.tiles-wrapper')`?

Comment: I wouldn't know how to do that, I mostly do CSS. Just trying to pick some jQuery/js skills up. Finding it hard to know where to start. Thanks though

Comment: The answer given by user "undefined" below is correct. A micro-optimization (so much so that I wouldn't bother including it as an answer) would be to use `.on('resize', function...)` instead of `.resize(function...` and when triggering as suggested by "undefined" using `.trigger('resize')` instead of `.resize()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cache the object and trigger the resize event, this way the resize handler is executed on DOM Ready.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    var $elem = $('.tiles-wrapper');
    $elem.css({
        top: '50%',
        left: '50%',
        margin: '-' + ($elem.height() / 2) + 'px 0 0 -' + ($elem.width() / 2) + 'px'
    });
}).resize()
```

Comment: An added optimization, if the number of elements with class `tiles-wrapper` is static, would be to move the definition of `$elem` out of the resize function and onto the line above. This would save requerying on every resize. This is especially true since the code is guaranteed to run at least once (if `resize` were not immediately triggered, it would be a tradeoff as to whether you query before or not).

Comment: Thank you very much, I do only have one class with tiles-wrapper defined so I have moved the definition of the elemnts outside the resize function. Seems to work flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

```
var $tilesWrapper = $('.tiles-wrapper');

function setWrapperStyle () {
  var halfWidth = $tilesWrapper.width() * 0.5;
  var halfHeight = $tilesWrapper.height() * 0.5;
  $tilesWrapper.css({
    top: '50%',
    left: '50%',
    margin: '-' + halfHeight + 'px 0 0 -' + halfWidth + 'px'
  });
}

setWrapperStyle();
$(window).on('resize', setWrapperStyle);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make a fonction with your first line :

```
function center(){
    $('.tiles-wrapper').css({top:'50%',left:'50%',margin:'-'+($('.tiles-wrapper').height() / 2)+'px 0 0 -'+($('.tiles-wrapper').width() / 2)+'px'});
}
```

and then you call it a first time and you call it when you resize your window:

```
center();
$(window).resize(center);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need jquery here ? 
You can use directly css

```
.tiles-wrapper{
top:50% ;
left:50% ;
width: //what u given
height: //what u given
margin-left: //tiles width/2
margin-right: //tiles height/2
position: //absolute or float
}
```

if you want to calculate height and width dynamically
just write this on document ready

```
var $elem = $('.tiles-wrapper');
    $elem.css({
        top: '50%',
        left: '50%',
        margin: '-' + ($elem.height() / 2) + 'px 0 0 -' + ($elem.width() / 2) + 'px'
    });
```

In re-size it will automatically on center position.

Comment: I dont know how big the container will be as it contains 8 boxes which any user can add to or remove. This changes the width and height of the container. I would usually just try and use css. And i have a css fallback which will work for the initial state. Thanks for your answer